# Dropdown required field error not diseapear after first selection in Chrome and IE

Tags: php, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, click, required

I have a PHP form with different types of input fields in which I used jQuery validation plug-in required fields. Everything works well in Firefox that is if user did not fill the required field, he will get error beside each field and as soon as he insert data in that field, the error will be disappeared.

**Problem:** Test my form in Chrome and IE: if I don't fill the required field and try to submit, I will receive the error (Till this point everything is OK), but when I select one item in dropdown, the error will NOT DISAPPEARED till I select another item or I click somewhere in the form!!

This is part of my code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#formId').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        q1: {
            required: true,
        },
        q2: {
            required: true,
        },
       "q5[]": {
            required: true,
        },
       "q6[]": {
            required: true,
        }
    },

      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {    
       if (element.attr("type") == "radio" || element.attr("type") == "checkbox" || element.attr("name") == "q5[]") {
             error.insertAfter($(element).parents('div').prev($('question')));

         } else {
           error.insertAfter(element);
          }
     }   

   }); 
 });
</script>
```

and here is the html for dropdown part:

```
<select name="q5[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px">
<?php

 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 $gi = geoip_open('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_STANDARD);
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $preselect_country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $ip);
 include('newCountry.php');
 $list_top = "<option>--------------------Leave blank--------------------</option>\n";
 $list_bottom = "";

 while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
   if($preselect_country == $line['country']){
    $list_top .= "<option value=\"{$line['country']}\">{$line['country']}</option>\n";
 }else{
    $list_bottom .= "<option value=\"{$line['country']}\">{$line['country']}   </option>\n";
 }
}
 echo $list_top . $list_bottom;

geoip_close($gi);

 ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: change `"q5[]"` to `q5[]` and same for `q6[]` in your js

Comment: @RamSharma: when I change it to q5[], the error messege for each field does not work at all! (I mean I just received one message on top of the page)